# MySQL error when trying to create many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many, mysql-workbench, relationship

Im trying to create a many to many relationship between 'Rol' and 'Permisos', here is my code

Table 'Rol':

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tienda_v1`.`rol` (
  `idrol` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre_rol` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idrol`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table 'Permiso':

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tienda_v1`.`permiso` (
  `idpermiso` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre_permiso` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idpermiso`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And here is what I'm trying:

```
CREATE TABLE `tienda_v1`.`rol_permiso`(
    `rol_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `permiso_id` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`rol_id`,`permiso_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `rol_permiso_rol`
        FOREIGN KEY `rol_table_fk` (`rol_id`) REFERENCES `rol` (`idrol`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `rol_permiso_permiso`
        FOREIGN KEY `permiso_table` (`permiso_id`) REFERENCES `permiso` (`idpermiso`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And throws me this Output:

> 17:25:39  CREATE TABLE `tienda_v1`.`rol_permiso`(  `rol_id` INT NOT
> NULL,     `permiso_id` INT NOT NULL,     PRIMARY
> KEY(`rol_id`,`permiso_id`),     CONSTRAINT `rol_permiso_rol`
> FOREIGN KEY `rol_table_fk` (`rol_id`) REFERENCES `rol` (`idrol`)
> ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,  CONSTRAINT `rol_permiso_permiso`
> FOREIGN KEY `permiso_table` (`permiso_id`) REFERENCES `permiso`
> (`idpermiso`)         ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE )ENGINE =
> InnoDB    Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'rol_id' and referenced
> column 'idrol' in foreign key constraint 'rol_permiso_rol' are
> incompatible. 0.000 sec

Anyone have any idea whats happening? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the tables provided.

Maybe you are using diffrent tables in your database?

run

```
 SHOW CREATE TABLE rol
```

and check if it is the same

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rol` (
>   `idrol` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `nombre_rol` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`idrol`))
> ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `permiso` (
>   `idpermiso` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `nombre_permiso` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`idpermiso`))
> ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `rol_permiso`(
>     `rol_id` INT NOT NULL,
>     `permiso_id` INT NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY(`rol_id`,`permiso_id`),
>     CONSTRAINT `rol_permiso_rol`
>         FOREIGN KEY `rol_table_fk` (`rol_id`) REFERENCES `rol` (`idrol`)
>         ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
>     CONSTRAINT `rol_permiso_permiso`
>         FOREIGN KEY `permiso_table` (`permiso_id`) REFERENCES `permiso` (`idpermiso`)
>         ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
> )ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=91c18bd6eb58a609935b7a379704a9a9)*

Comment: Omg thanks! Didn't know about that command, for some reason primary key on 'Rol' was unsigned, I changed it and it worked! Thanks!